# How can you easily request the gmaps4rails gem to geocode an address on update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

there is a great gem for Rails 3 and Google Maps v3 integration (gmaps4rails) - I'm not a good Rails dev. but it worked within 15 minutes for me!!

I have one question though, I've been trying to get the geocoder to fire on every save/update/edit view to make sure the pin/map is always up-to-date (the records will not be edited very often so I can let the efficiency downside of this slide) but I am unable to get "check_process" to work as an argument. has anyone had any experience with this one? if so, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple:

There was a bug in the gem, so I guess you did things right:

```
acts_as_gmappable :check_process => false
```

Corrected in 0.6.5.

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: that is exactly what i was trying and with the updated gem it works a treat so thank you!